# Erratic cursor in NetBeans 8.2 IDE, JDK 1.8. Keyboard lag?

Tags: java, netbeans-8

I have a student who experiences his cursor jumping around erratically under NetBeans 8.2 and JDK 1.8.x on a MacBook Pro (High Sierra).  Other applications work fine, but when he starts typing in NetBeans, he'll get a delay, then the cursor will jump a couple characters, left or right, maybe one of the characters he types will appear, but not all of them.  If he pauses for, say, .5 a sec between keypresses, it works fine but that, of course, is untenable.
  I reinstalled a fresh install and have the same problem.  Can anyone help?  This is beyond me.  TIA
Thank you skomisa.  Here's some of the log file.  No ERRORS.

```
>Log Session: Wednesday, April 18, 2018 11:05:58 AM MDT\
>System Info: \
  Product Version         = NetBeans IDE 8.2 (Build 201609300101) (#5fd841261bf9)\
  Operating System        = Mac OS X version 10.13.4 running on x86_64\
  Java; VM; Vendor        = 1.8.0_161; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.161-b12; Oracle Corporation\
  Runtime                 = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_161-b12\
  Java Home               = /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre\
  System Locale; Encoding = en_US (nb); UTF-8\
  Home Directory          = /Users/avery.phillips\
  Current Directory       = /\
  User Directory          = /Users/avery.phillips/Library/Application Support/NetBeans/8.2\
  Cache Directory         = /Users/avery.phillips/Library/Caches/NetBeans/8.2\
  Installation            = /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/nb\
                            /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide\
                            /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/extide\
                            /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/java\
                            /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/apisupport\
                            /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/websvccommon\
                            /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/profiler\
                            /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/harness\
                            /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/javafx\
                            /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform\
  Boot & Ext. Classpath   = /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/classes:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/System/Library/Java/Extensions/MRJToolkit.jar\
  Application Classpath   = /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/lib/boot.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/lib/org-openide-modules.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/lib/org-openide-util-lookup.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/lib/org-openide-util-ui.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/lib/org-openide-util.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/lib/locale/boot_ja.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/lib/locale/boot_pt_BR.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/lib/locale/boot_ru.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/lib/locale/boot_zh_CN.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-modules_ja.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-modules_pt_BR.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-modules_ru.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-modules_zh_CN.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-lookup_ja.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-lookup_pt_BR.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-lookup_ru.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-lookup_zh_CN.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-ui_ja.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-ui_pt_BR.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-ui_ru.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-ui_zh_CN.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util_ja.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util_pt_BR.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util_ru.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util_zh_CN.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar\
  Startup Classpath       = /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/core/asm-all-5.0.1.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/core/core-base.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/core/core.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/core/org-netbeans-libs-asm.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/core/org-openide-filesystems-compat8.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/core/org-openide-filesystems.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/core/locale/core-base_ja.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/core/locale/core-base_pt_BR.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/core/locale/core-base_ru.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/core/locale/core-base_zh_CN.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/core/locale/core_ja.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/core/locale/core_pt_BR.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/core/locale/core_ru.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/core/locale/core_zh_CN.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/core/locale/org-netbeans-libs-asm_ja.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/core/locale/org-netbeans-libs-asm_pt_BR.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/core/locale/org-netbeans-libs-asm_ru.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/core/locale/org-netbeans-libs-asm_zh_CN.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/core/locale/org-openide-filesystems-compat8_ja.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/core/locale/org-openide-filesystems-compat8_pt_BR.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/core/locale/org-openide-filesystems-compat8_ru.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/core/locale/org-openide-filesystems-compat8_zh_CN.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/core/locale/org-openide-filesystems_ja.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/core/locale/org-openide-filesystems_pt_BR.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/core/locale/org-openide-filesystems_ru.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/core/locale/org-openide-filesystems_zh_CN.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/nb/core/org-netbeans-upgrader.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/nb/core/locale/core_nb.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/nb/core/locale/core_nb_ja.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/nb/core/locale/core_nb_pt_BR.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/nb/core/locale/core_nb_ru.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/nb/core/locale/core_nb_zh_CN.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/nb/core/locale/org-netbeans-upgrader_ja.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/nb/core/locale/org-netbeans-upgrader_pt_BR.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/nb/core/locale/org-netbeans-upgrader_ru.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/nb/core/locale/org-netbeans-upgrader_zh_CN.jar\
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------\
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.netbinox]: Install area set to file:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/\
WARNING [org.netbeans.core.modules]: the modules [org.netbeans.modules.form.nb] use org.jdesktop.layout which is deprecated: Use javax.swing.GroupLayout instead. (In form editor: select Form ... in Inspector; change Layout Generation Style to Standard Java 6 code.)\
WARNING [org.netbeans.core.modules]: the modules [org.netbeans.modules.java.editor.lib, org.netbeans.modules.xml.text] use org.netbeans.modules.editor.deprecated.pre65formatting which is deprecated.\
WARNING [org.netbeans.core.modules]: the modules [org.netbeans.modules.ide.kit, org.netbeans.modules.xml.text] use org.netbeans.modules.editor.structure which is deprecated.\
WARNING [org.netbeans.core.modules]: the modules [org.netbeans.modules.apisupport.ant, org.netbeans.modules.java.hints, org.netbeans.modules.maven.hints] use org.netbeans.modules.java.hints.legacy.spi which is deprecated: Use Java Hints SPI (org.netbeans.spi.java.hints) instead.\
INFO [org.netbeans.core.startup.NbEvents]: Turning on modules:\
..... there were a slew of org.opentide... or org.netbeans... lines after this...like 500+ lines
    org.openide.util.lookup [8.33.1 201609300101]\
    org.openide.util [9.7.1 201609300101]\
    org.openide.util.ui [9.6.1 201609300101]\
    org.openide.modules [7.48.1 201609300101]\
    org.netbeans.api.annotations.common/1 [1.27.1 201609300101]\
... and some eclipse...and apache...
    org.eclipse.core.contenttype [3.4.100 3.4.100.v20110423-0524]\
    org.apache.xmlrpc [3.0.0 3.0.0]\
    org.apache.ws.commons.util [1.0.1 1.0.1]\
    org.apache.commons.lang [2.6 2.6]\
    com.jcraft.jzlib [1.0.7 1.0.7]\
    com.googlecode.javaewah.JavaEWAH [0.7.9 0.7.9]\
    com.google.guava [15.0.0 15.0.0]\
...then some more INFO lines...and other stuff...
INFO [org.netbeans.core.netigso.Netigso]: bundle org.eclipse.osgi@3.9.1.v20140110-1610 started\
INFO [org.netbeans.core.network.proxy.NetworkProxyReloader]: System network proxy resolver: Mac\
...I left this in in case it's relevant...
INFO [org.netbeans.core.network.proxy.NetworkProxyReloader]: System network proxy TEST - http port: 0\
Diagnostic information\
Input arguments:\
    -Djdk.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home\
    -Dnetbeans.default_userdir_root=/Users/avery.phillips/Library/Application Support/NetBeans\
    -Dnetbeans.dirs=/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/nb:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ergonomics:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/extide:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/java:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/apisupport:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/webcommon:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/websvccommon:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/enterprise:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/mobility:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/profiler:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/python:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/php:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/identity:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/harness:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/cnd:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/cndext:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/dlight:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/groovy:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/extra:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/javacard:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/javafx:\
    -Dnetbeans.home=/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform\
    -Dnetbeans.importclass=org.netbeans.upgrade.AutoUpgrade\
    -Dnetbeans.accept_license_class=org.netbeans.license.AcceptLicense\
    -Xmx1024m\
    -Xss2m\
    -Xms32m\
    -Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true\
    -Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true\
    -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true\
    -Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true\
    -Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true\
    -DaddExports:java.desktop/com.apple.eawt=ALL-UNNAMED\
    -DaddExports:java.desktop/sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED\
    -DaddExports:java.base/jdk.internal.jrtfs=ALL-UNNAMED\
    -DaddExports:java.desktop/apple.laf=ALL-UNNAMED\
    -DaddExports:java.desktop/java.awt.peer=ALL-UNNAMED\
    -DaddExports:java.desktop/com.sun.beans.editors=ALL-UNNAMED\
    -DaddExports:java.desktop/sun.awt.im=ALL-UNNAMED\
    -DaddExports:java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED\
    -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError\
    -XX:HeapDumpPath=/Users/avery.phillips/Library/Application Support/NetBeans/8.2/var/log/heapdump.hprof\
Compiler: HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers\
Heap memory usage: initial 32.0MB maximum 910.5MB\
Non heap memory usage: initial 2.4MB maximum -1b\
Garbage collector: PS Scavenge (Collections=16 Total time spent=0s)\
Garbage collector: PS MarkSweep (Collections=3 Total time spent=0s)\
Classes: loaded=9854 total loaded=9854 unloaded 0\
INFO [org.netbeans.core.ui.warmup.DiagnosticTask]: Total memory 17,179,869,184\
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Resolving dependencies took: 1,100 ms\
INFO [org.netbeans.spi.project.support.ant.GlobFileBuiltQuery]: Found target for /Users/avery.phillips/Desktop/comsci/netbeans projects/NBExercises/src/nbexercises/NBExercises.java: /Users/avery.phillips/Desktop/comsci/netbeans projects/NBExercises/build/classes/nbexercises/NBExercises.class\
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Complete indexing of 19 binary roots took: 276 ms\
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: /Users/avery.phillips/Desktop/comsci/netbeans projects/NBExercises/src took: 100 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 1 ms]\
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: /Users/avery.phillips/Desktop/comsci/netbeans projects/NBExercises/test took: 40 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]\
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Complete indexing of 2 source roots took: 140 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 1 ms]\
WARNING [org.openide.util.WeakListenerImpl]: Can't remove javax.swing.event.ChangeListener using method org.netbeans.modules.java.j2seproject.J2SEActionProvider$CosAction.removeChangeListener from org.netbeans.modules.java.j2seproject.J2SEActionProvider$CosAction@2be19745\
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.autoupdate.updateprovider.AutoupdateCatalogParser]: Unpaired license 00000008 without any module.\
WARNING [org.openide.filesystems.Ordering]: Not all children in Templates/ marked with the position attribute: [SaaSServices], but some are: [JFX, JWS, Licenses, NetBeansModuleDevelopment-files, Privileged, Project, Recent, Services, NetBeansModuleDevelopment, ClientSide, OSGi, SpringFramework, Classes, javafx, GUIForms, Beans, AWTForms, UnitTests, SeleniumTests, Persistence, Hibernate, XML, Other, Properties]\
WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.options.keymap.LayersBridge]: Invalid shortcut: org.openide.loaders.BrokenDataShadow@16854ac1[MultiFileObject@7f499a8[Keymaps/NetBeans/D-BACK_QUOTE.shadow]]\
WARNING [null]: Last record repeated again.\
}
```

Comment: In [NetBeans Bug 269024](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=269024)  another user also reports  "inserting a single character can take half a second" but the issue was on Linux and is unresolved. Three things to check [1] Make sure you are running with the latest JDK update (8u162). [2] If you are using a special look and feel  (e.g. Darcula) try reverting to the default. [3] If you are using any special fonts try reverting to the defaults.

Comment: Also, is the slow typing problem only for *.java files, or is it for all file types? For example, create a simple text file and edit that in  NetBeans. Is typing still slow? If so, update your post with the NetBeans log: from the **View** menu select **IDE Log** to display that.

Comment: The problem seems to be in other files too (at least in a text file).  I'll add the log file to my original question

Comment: Auuggh, noobie here doesn't know how to attach a file.  Netbeans log file is too long to paste into my original post.

Comment: Just examine messages prefixed **WARNING** or **ERROR** and update your post with such messages if they seem to be relevant. There may not be any. Also, from that log can you update your post with the five lines prefixed **Product Version**, **Operating System**, **Java; VM; Vendor**, **Runtime** and **Java Home**. They will be near the start of the log.

Answer (score 0):

The problem disappeared when the student worked at home and his grandfather worked on the computer.  His solution is below.  I did that in the school environment and now it seems like typing characters in a single sentence works normally but when I press CR or backspace or if I delete one or more lines, there is a big lag (2-3 seconds?).

*step 1: go to system preference >network>select your wifi connection>advanced>select proxies tab.
Then check the 3 options 1) auto proxy discovery 2)automatic proxy configuration 3) web proxy(http)*

*step 2: go to netbeans>preferences>general> select use system proxy> reload> test connection*

*step 3: if connection is successful, then clean & build your applications in netbeans and press run*

*The problem probably happened because a High Sierra update by default might have blocked the sites which use system proxy settings.  When Avery updates the latest OS security update to 10.13.4 (which just became available yesterday) he may encounter the same issue again.*

Comment: So can you try using a wired connection on the same computer to see which problems (if any) get resolved? If everything is fine when you are not using a wireless connection then at least you know where the problem lies!

Comment: Also, another Mac user on Mac Os 10.13.4 had cursor/scrollbar problems which were fixed by using a more recent DEV version of NetBeans. That may not be an option in your case, but take a look: [Netbeans 8.2 : Scrollbar not following cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50002033/netbeans-8-2-scrollbar-not-following-cursor#comment87034187_50002033)