# Netbeans 8.2 : Scrollbar not following cursor

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

So i updated from Netbeans 8.0.2 to 8.2 and now i have this very annoying bug : when i move the cursor down, the scrollbar won't auto scroll, so the cursor simply disappears ! I need to manually scroll to get the cursor visible again.

I'm on Mac Os 10.13.4. Anyone had this bug and could fix it ? Otherwise i'll have downgrade to get my things done properly again.

Thanks !

Comment: I checked NetBeans bugs and don't see an exact match for your problem, but there are [plenty of similar ones](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=269894). Note that bugs marked as RESOLVED haven't necessarily been applied to the released version of 8.2.  However, [you could use a DEV version of NetBeans](http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/) that would have the fixes applied, and as an added bonus you could also use JDK9 which you can't do on 8.2. That approach might be preferable to downgrading. Also note that the DEV version of NB could run concurrently with 8.2.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, tried the last nightly version but i keep getting a lot of 'java.lang.StackOverflowError' after opening it. But i tested and the above bug is fixed in this version

Comment: But is the StackOverflowError issue now resolved? I haven't seen that before. Also, if you decide to stick with the DEV version don't forget to install any plugins (**Tools > Plugins**) you may have installed with 8.0.2 and/or 8.2.

Comment: @skomisa The StackOverFlowError did not happened after i restarted the IDE. The problem seems to be fixed, thank you ! Please add as a reply, i will accept it ;)

Comment: Years later i received a notification about this question ; i moved to VS Code, it's so much better and faster. I'd suggest anyone using Netbeans, to do the same.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'd only mention that this is a fairly old question, and there have been several major releases of NetBeans since you posted it. If you are happy using VSCode then you probably want to stick with it, but you can always [download NetBeans 12.5](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb125/nb125.html) and give it a try if you feel so inclined.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about MacOS but I have noticed that behavior on Linux too. It happens every time I type an accented character (e.g. á, é).

The solution I've found is adding `env XMODIFIERS=""` to the beginning of the command line in the .desktop file (the default is XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus on Ubuntu 20.04). Or simply starting it from the command line as `XMODIFIERS="" netbeans`

I'm posting this a little late because it's becoming increasingly difficult to find old versions of NetBeans after they moved from Oracle to Apache. So if you are stuck with a specific version and can't downgrade/upgrade, this answer might be helpful.

Comment: I'm glad it works. I think there might be another solution adding/removing an .xinputrc file in your home dir, but it's a little hard to double check everything to be sure what is really doing its job (restarting the session, restarting the app, etc.). FWIW my .xinputrc currently contains `run_im ibus`.

Comment: @skomisa You are right, the op asked for macOS, not Linux! Sorry

Answer (score 0):

I [checked NetBeans bugs](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=cursor%20scroll) and don't see an exact match for your problem, but there are plenty of similar ones. Note that bugs marked as RESOLVED haven't necessarily been applied to the released version of 8.2.

However, you could use a [DEV version of NetBeans](http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/) that would have the fixes applied, and as an added bonus you could also use JDK9 which you can't do on 8.2. That approach might be preferable to downgrading. Also note that the DEV version of NB could run concurrently with 8.2.

Comment: Even the DEV version had this bug when i tried it. Unfortunately i had to downgrade.