# Netbeans 8.2 - Typing lag and delays while writing code

Tags: netbeans

I am experiencing terrible typing lag issues (as in, basically unusable). Every 15 or 20 seconds, the IDE just pauses and does something (as in, "thinking"?) for a solid 4 or 5 seconds, and then continues with whatever activity I was doing.

If I start typing a line of code, I may get half of the line typed and then the editor will freeze, and I can continue typing but nothing appears on the screen. Then after 4 or 5 seconds, all of the characters I typed will appear almost instantly, but of course, since I can't see what I'm typing, I wind up with typos and have to backtrack. I can't write three short lines of code without this happening.

I have tried:
- uninstalling and reinstalling

Here is my Machine Specs:
Operating System : Windows 10
Processor : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6650U CPU @ 2.20GHz 2.21 GHz
Installed RAM: 16 GB
System type : 64-bit operating System,X64-based processor

is anyone facing the same problem? 
what is the solution to fix such issue?

Comment: [1] The NetBeans log (**View > IDE Log**) may show some issues/errors, so update your post if there is anything relevant there. [2] Is your machine functioning perfectly normally except within NetBeans? [3] Open Windows Task Manager and go through the various options on the Performance tab (CPU, etc.). Anything?  [4] It's not a duplicate, but [Erratic cursor in NetBeans 8.2 IDE, JDK 1.8. Keyboard lag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49821989/erratic-cursor-in-netbeans-8-2-ide-jdk-1-8-keyboard-lag) might be helpful.

Comment: Hi Skomisa . i read the log as you recommended and i found no issues there. also my Machine as i mentioned my specs in my Post is fine and the netbeans was working awesome before. no even warning issues logged into our Windows log related to that matter. i went and i logged issue under netbeans Support site and they recommended to install the netbeans IDE 9. i did that but i faced another issue where when i right click on Java Programe to run i found no action( No Output) even with simple class as Hello World..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its a support question which belongs on the support forum of the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was closed as a NetBeans support question but few years later I also experience this and it's that annoying. I am using `Darcula Look and Feel`, **NetBeans 8.2RC** and **Java8**. Went to ***options>Look and Feel>Preferred look and feel***, selected a different look and feel (Metal) and restarted the IDE. The typing got back to normal. Switched back to Darcula and typing is still okay.